# date.value = new Date(date.value); doesn't work in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

It works in other web browser but IE11 returns Invalid Date.
In order to debug I used below code.

```
console.log('before - ' + date.value); 
date.value = new Date(date.value); 
console.log('after - ' + date.value);
```

IE11 Console

before -1958-08-21 00:00:00.0
after -Invalid Date

Chrom Version 75.0.3770.80
before -1958-08-21 00:00:00.0
after -Thu Aug 21 1958 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
new Date("1958-08-21 00:00:00.0");
```

is a non-standard way to use the function.

```
new Date("1958-08-21T00:00:00.0");
```

works in IE11. (I added the `T`).

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> A string value representing a date, specified in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (these formats are IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also strings in a version of ISO8601).

Comment: Yeah i was looking in to something similar. The given date should be an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 formatted date. 
Is there a js function to convert the date in to acceptable date format or i would have to write something by my own. 

I am dealing with dynamic dates in a loop.

Comment: What is the source of the date? Maybe you can get it in a compliant format.

Comment: I receive it dynamically based on the user and it is in JSON.

Comment: Ok .. that kind of seems like a worst case scenario. You receive a value that someone pinky promises is a date. Try to parse it as best you can I guess? Maybe just slap a `T` in there and see if `new Date()` returns a valid date?

Comment: I hardcoded T inside in one case to test it and it worked. IE returned the correct date but i don't know which format of date i will receive from JSON. I was wondering if there is any function which could change it to acceptable format but i guess i will have to write one by my own. 
But thank you for looking into it (y)

Comment: Sure i will check it out. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah i changed the query for the JSON to have T instead of space and its working smooth now. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that you have solved the issue. Then you could mark Halcyon's answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.